# Is it possible in Blazor to close a circuit while another task still needs it?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am getting the following error occasionally. And in different places.

```
Error 02:26:42 [] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager - Navigation failed when changing the location to /Manager/Dashboard JSDisconnectedException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the circuit has disconnected and is being disposed.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(Int64 asyncHandle, String identifier, String argsJson, JSCallResultType resultType, Int64 targetInstanceId)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<NavigateToCore>g__PerformNavigationAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
Error 02:26:42 [] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost - Unhandled exception in circuit '-5JHigSs3RCwrNJcEKupxdNLrFtlNwcQDeAHENgzco8'. JSDisconnectedException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the circuit has disconnected and is being disposed.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(Int64 asyncHandle, String identifier, String argsJson, JSCallResultType resultType, Int64 targetInstanceId)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<NavigateToCore>g__PerformNavigationAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
```

I'm guessing this means that the `NavigationManager` is trying to redirect on a circuit that has been closed.

I'm unaware of a way in Blazor to directly access the circuit. But obviously, circuits are closed when appropriate. And I can understand that may be happening as part of leaving one page to navigate to another.

What should I be looking for to figure this out? Unfortunately there are 17 places where it will navigate to `/Manager/Dashboard` so I have virtually no information about where this is happening.

Comment: Where is the Interop call placed, relative to the call to Navigate?

Comment: Is there a long running task server-side actually causing the circuit to disconnect and is prerendering turned on? With respect to directly accessing the circuit, it is possible. [See here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWYUIjWKh7w).

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I have no idea. This has never happened on my system so it's reports I'm getting from the QA and beta testers. And there's no consistency to when it happens or on what page.

Comment: @clamchoda Unless I missed something in that video, the problem he discusses is having my code close the circuit. I believe I never do that. I do set, in _Host.cshtml `render-mode="Server"` thanks

Comment: @DavidThielen Sorry for the confusion. I was thinking you could use the video to capture *when* the circuit disconnects to help debug the issue, but from your comments it doesn't look like this is an error produced on your testing environment. I do see this error when render mode is `ServerPrerendered` and JS is invoked to early in the component life cycle, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Do you have any services that invoke javascript on a timer?

Comment: Yeah, that's very common for things to work fine on dev system and fail IRL.  I had a multiplayer game that ultimately failed due to circuit issues on weak connections-- they'd drop in and out, but while they were out, it would cause `async` methods to fail.  My guess is that due to latency, you are calling JS interop AFTER the server has initiated the navigation, but BEFORE the circuit to the new page is completed?  In that case, a solution might be to manually disable whatever JS is called on the component before you start navigating?  Just throwing spaghetti at the wall here. . .